# Find row with the most true value columns

Tags: sql

Table User

| estado_id | user_id | shopping | mercado | feira |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Table Cidade

| estado_id | version_id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | jose | shopping |
| 1 | 2 | maria | feira |
| 1 | 2 | maria | mercado |
| 1 | 3 | bruna | mercado |

I need to compare the states, and bring only those that cover user x criteria's, but the user table may contain hundreds of users and I just have to return to which user x is bound. In the users table, I need to bring everyone that they think matches. If in the shopping and fair table the value is 1 and market to 0 then shopping and fair must be returned within these versions, I managed to bring up only the user data / id_state, however when I compare the user table = 1 with the city table type = shopping
But I cannot find a way to do that, because' it needs to be dynamic

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT cidade.*, uv.user_id, uv.shopping, uv.mercado, uv.feira
    FROM cidade
    INNER JOIN userst as uv ON cidade.estado_id = uv.estado_id
    WHERE cidade.estado_id = 1 AND uv.user_id = 1
)
SELECT [type], shopping, mercado, feira
FROM CTE
```

My expectation

| estado_id | version_id | name | type | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | jose | shopping | 1 |

```
CREATE TABLE cidade(
    estado_id int,
    version_id int,
    name varchar(255),
    [type] varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE userst (
    estado_id int,
    user_id int,
    shopping int,
    mercado int,
     feira int
);

INSERT INTO cidade (estado_id, version_id, name, [type])
    VALUES (1, 1, 'jose', 'shopping')
    , (1, 2, 'maria', 'feira')
    , (1, 2, 'maria', 'mercado')
    , (1, 3, 'bruna', 'mercado');    

INSERT INTO userst (estado_id, user_id, shopping, mercado, feira)
    VALUES (1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
    , (1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
    , (1, 3, 1, 0, 1);
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> PostgreSQL - please correct your tags to the actual RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I have to say I don't understand you matching logic either. For example why isn't "maria:mercado" being returned? There is a 1 in the "mercado" column of the user table.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting RDBMS tags... feel free to add back the correct one.